# How to calculate Precision,Recall and F1 score using sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate the `Precision, Recall and F1`  in this sample code. I have calculated the accuracy of the model on train and test dataset. Kindly help to calculate these matrices.
Please look at the code I have comment every important line for an explanation.

```
# develop a classifier for the Faces Dataset
from numpy import load
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pickle
# load dataset
data = load('faces-embeddings.npz')
trainX, trainy, testX, testy = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1'], data['arr_2'], data['arr_3']
print('Dataset: train=%d, test=%d' % (trainX.shape[0], testX.shape[0]))
# normalize input vectors
in_encoder = Normalizer(norm='l2')
trainX = in_encoder.transform(trainX)
testX = in_encoder.transform(testX)
# label encode targets
out_encoder = LabelEncoder()
out_encoder.fit(trainy)
trainy = out_encoder.transform(trainy)
testy = out_encoder.transform(testy)
# fit model
model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
#Saving Model
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
# predict
yhat_train = model.predict(trainX)
yhat_test = model.predict(testX)
# score
score_train = accuracy_score(trainy, yhat_train)
score_test = accuracy_score(testy, yhat_test)
# summarize
print('Accuracy: train=%.3f, test=%.3f' % (score_train*100, score_test*100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

knowing the true value of Y (trainy here) and the predicted value of Y (yhat_train here) you can directly compute the precision, recall and F1 score, exactly as you did for the accuracy (thanks to sklearn.metrics):

sklearn.metrics.precision_score(trainy,yhat_train)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score

sklearn.metrics.recall_score(trainy,yhat_train)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score

sklearn.metrics.f1_score(trainy,yhat_train)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score